# player.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'Player' has already been declared laravel-6

Tags: javascript, canvas, laravel-6

i have an laravel project and just implemented some scripts in it 
and i keep gettinf this error
*Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'Player' has already been declared
    at player.js:1*
*Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'canvas' has already been declared
    at tetris.js:1*
i only get this error while working with laravel because the code works in a normal html file.
this is my javascript:

```
player.js
    class Player
{
    constructor()
    {
    this.pos = {x:0,y:0};
    this.matrix = null;
    this.score = 0;
    }
}

tetris.jsconst canvas = document.getElementById('tetris');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.scale(20, 20);
context.fillStyle = '#000';
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

context.strokeStyle = '#cbc7ca';
context.strokeRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

function arenaSweep() {
    let rowCount = 1
  outer: for(let y = arena.length - 1; y > 0; --y) {
        for(let x = 0; x < arena[y].length; ++x) {
            if(arena[y][x] === 0){
                continue outer;
            }
        }

       const row = arena.splice(y, 1)[0].fill(0);
       arena.unshift(row);
       ++y;

       player.score += rowCount * 10;
       rowCount *= 2;
    }
}

function collide(arena, player){
    const [m, o] = [player.matrix, player.pos];
    for(let y = 0; y < m.length; ++y) {
        for(let x = 0; x < m[y].length; ++x){
            if(m[y][x] !== 0 &&
                (arena[y + o.y] &&
                arena[y + o.y][x + o.x]) !== 0)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function createMatrix(w, h){
    const matrix = [];
    while( h--) {
        matrix.push(new Array(w).fill(0));
    }
    return matrix
}

function draw() {
    context.fillStyle = '#000';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    drawMatrix(arena, {x:0, y:0});
    drawMatrix(player.matrix, player.pos );
}

function createPiece(type) {
    if( type === 'T'){
      return  [
            [0,0,0],
            [1,1,1],
            [0,1,0],
        ];
    }
    else if(type === 'O'){
        return [
            [2,2],
            [2,2]
        ];

    }
    else if( type === 'L'){
        return  [
              [0,3,0],
              [0,3,0],
              [0,3,3],
          ];
    }
    else  if( type === 'J'){
        return  [
              [0,4,0],
              [0,4,0],
              [4,4,0],
          ];
    }
    else if( type === 'I'){
        return  [
              [0,5,0,0],
              [0,5,0,0],
              [0,5,0,0],
              [0,5,0,0],
          ];
    }
    else if( type === 'Z'){
        return  [
              [6,6,0],
              [0,6,6],
              [0,0,0],
          ];
    }
    else if( type === 'S'){
        return  [
              [0,7,7],
              [7,7,0],
              [0,0,0],
          ];
    }
}

function drawMatrix(matrix, offset){
    matrix.forEach((row, y) => {
        row.forEach((value, x) => {
            if(value !== 0) {
                context.fillStyle = colors[value];
                context.fillRect(x + offset.x,
                                 y + offset.y, 
                                 1,1);
            }
        });
    });
}


function merge(arena, player) {
    player.matrix.forEach((row, y) => {
        row.forEach((value, x) => {
            if(value !== 0) {
                arena[y + player.pos.y][x + player.pos.x] = value;
            }
        });
    });
}

function playerDrop() {
    player.pos.y++;
    if(collide(arena, player)) {
        player.pos.y--;
        merge(arena,player);
        playerReset();
        arenaSweep();
        updateScore();
    }
    dropCounter = 0;
}

function playerMove(dir) {
    player.pos.x += dir;
    if(collide(arena, player)) {
        player.pos.x -= dir;
    }
}

function playerReset() {
    const pieces = 'ILJOSZ';
    player.matrix = createPiece(pieces[pieces.length * Math.random() | 0]);
    player.pos.y = 0;
    player.pos.x = (arena[0].length / 2 | 0) -
                    (player.matrix[0].length / 2 | 0);
    if(collide(arena,player)) {
        arena.forEach(row => row.fill(0));
        player.score = 0;
        playerReset();
    }

}

function playerRotate(dir){
    const pos = player.pos.x;
    let offset = 1;
    rotate(player.matrix, dir);
    while (collide(arena, player)) {
            player.pos.x += offset;
            offset = -(offset +(offset > 0 ? 1 : -1 ));
            if(offset > player.matrix[0].length) {
                rotate(player.matrix, -dir);
                player.pos.x = pos;
                return;
            }
    }
}

function rotate(matrix, dir){
    for(let y = 0; y < matrix.length;++y) {
        for(let x = 0; x < y; ++x) {
            [
                matrix[x][y],
                matrix[y][x],
            ] = [
                matrix[y][x],
                matrix[x][y],
            ];
        }
    }

    if(dir > 0){
        matrix.forEach(row => row.reverse());
    }else{
        matrix.reverse();
    }
}
let dropCounter = 0;
let dropInterval = 1000;


let lasttime = 0;
function update(time = 0) {
    const deltaTime = time - lasttime;
    lasttime = time;
    dropCounter += deltaTime;
    if(dropCounter > dropInterval){
       playerDrop();
    }
    draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function updateScore() {
    document.getElementById('score').innerText = player.score;
}

const colors =[
    null,
    'purple',
    'yellow',
    'orange',
    'blue',
    'cyan',
    'red',
    'green',
];

const arena = createMatrix(12, 20);
const player = new Player;

document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
    if (event.keyCode === 37){
        playerMove(-1);
    }
    else if(event.keyCode === 39){
        playerMove(1);
    }
    else if(event.keyCode === 40){
     playerDrop();
    }
    else if(event.keyCode === 90) {
        playerRotate(-1);
    }
    else if(event.keyCode === 88) {
        playerRotate(1);
    }
})

playerReset();
updateScore();
update();
```

this is my blade template:

```
@section('content')
    <div id="score">0</div>


    <canvas id="tetris" width="240" height="400"></canvas>


    <script type="application/javascript" src="{{asset('js/player.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="{{asset('js/tetris.js')}}"></script>
@endsection`
```

Comment: so I see you're using standard blade templating. Just a note for the future, I never put my scripts in the content section. It's a little more efficient to place them in a section below it called "footer-scripts" or something and then @yield the footer scripts section in the main layout. The only reason I suggest this is, is because is there a chance that you're calling it in the section of this view as well as in the main layout you're using? double declaring?

Comment: it could also be that you're passing in "player" as a parameter in one of your functions but then also declaring it as a "const" later on down the script. maybe try changing the name of the passed in parameter and leave your const by the same name.